# Move default config folder of eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ide

When Eclipse first start, it creates some config files and folders on my hard drive (contains information about work-space ...etc...). I don't like the position it creates config files because config files are all put in my C:\Users\Long folder and that's ugly. I want to put all those config files somewhere else (C:\Eclipse\ for example). This happens in Linux too.

Do you know how to put those files in somewhere else?

Answer (score 21):

Just add the following to your `eclipse.ini` file (found at the root eclipse installation folder):

```
-Dosgi.configuration.area=file:/C:/Workspace/.eclipse
```

Comment: This will not solve the problem, C:/Workspace/.eclipse will be created, but also there will be .eclipse and .p2 folders created in user.home directory... at least in windows platform (and eclipse neon).

Comment: @MrSimpleMind You can add 'eclipse.p2.data.area=@config.dir/../p2' and the .eclipse issue seems to be solved with Oxygen (4.7).

Comment: @usr1234567 I will try oxygen and check this, I really hope it is fixed! I have  a thread, and forum discussion here for more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39168906/

Comment: @usr1234567 Not working for me... any idea? The folders are still created under c:\users\{USER}

Comment: I have found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10017395/change-secure-storage-directory-in-eclipse-user-home-path-issue-on-windows which seems to work by changing the user home to the location you like. Don't know if it is safe to do that

Answer (score 2):

To change the default .eclipse folder location, go to ${eclipse.home}, open your eclipse.ini with a text editor and insert there one line more:

-Dosgi.configuration.area=/path_to_new_folder_location/.eclipse/

Comment: why the downvote? That's valid answer. Downvote for unreasonable downvotes and upvotes for answer. Be nice and precise to newcomers, plz.

Comment: @FaithReaper: I'm not the downvoter, but this answer is exactly the same as the most upvoted one. It adds nothing.

Comment: @zb226 Now I see this. It is different in wording, but is not copying anyway.. I think it neither deserves upvotes nor downvotes..

Answer (score 2):

As someone already said, adding the property `-Dosgi.configuration.area` in the `eclipse.ini` file does the trick.

But in my opinion it would be better to rely on the `user.home` variable and set the destination like for the other variables.

Example with `-Dosgi.instance.area.default`:

```
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
```

In my case I just wanted another destination than the default `@user.home/.eclipse` which was still used by the Eclipse Mars that I keep for old projects and I just defined:

```
-Dosgi.configuration.area=@user.home/.eclipse-oygen-3
```

to have a specific destination for the Eclipse Oxygen 3 installation.

Note that syntax works for both Windows and Linux (I did not tested on OSX, but I guess it should).

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse has some [command line arguments](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/running_eclipse.htm) you can use. One of those arguments is the flag `-data` which tells Eclipse where the workspace of Eclipse should be located.

So when I create a new workspace, I normally create a shortcut under Windows (or script file under Linux) with the following contents:

```
eclipse.exe -vm <JDK>\bin\javaw.exe" -data ws -nl en
```

This defines which JDK should be used, that the workspace is located under `ws` and that the english locale should be used.

Comment: Sorry! That's not what I asked for. This is what I asked for:

http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/671060/

I hate the .eclipse folder and I want it to go somewhere else, wherever, just stay out of my home folder!

Comment: I have read what you pointed at, and I don't think you are right. I never ever has an additional folder created for me, I only have the eclipse installation directory, and the workspace directory. So skip my answer, but enhance your question if you want a proper answer ...

Comment: I have rechecked at home and started eclipse just by doubleclick on `eclipse.exe` under Windows 7. I get asked which workspace to use, and when I ask the open eclipse its configuration (`Help > About Eclipse Platform > Configuration Details`) I find the following line `osgi.configuration.area=file:/D:/programme/java/eclipse/eclipse-europa-fall/configuration/` which is exactly the installation directory of my eclipse.

Comment: In the link I provided above, there is a post at the end. It said: "No luck here, I fear. To be clear, what I mean by 'no luck' is that when I make my config changes and restart Eclipse, it just recreates a .eclipse directory in $HOME and asks me where to put my workspace, rather than just finding it. Any more ideas?"

It said about the .eclipse folder.

I forgot to mention that I was using Spring System Tool Suite. But Spring STS is Eclipse-based so I think Eclipse is the same.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO parameter **-configuration** does the trick. It must point to a subdirectory named "config". Eclipse will fill this and the upper directory itself with files, e.g. for a JBoss server installation.

If you have more than one eclipse installation, then you should use a different directory for each eclipse installation.

Example how to keep everything in defined places:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\eclipse\eclipse48jee\eclipse.exe" -nl en_US -vm "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\bin" **-configuration C:\EclipseData\eclipse48jee\config** -data C:\Workspaces\SomeProject