# Problems running Eclipse Indigo

Tags: eclipse, java

I'm trying to run Eclipse Indigo, but every time i click the application (eclipsec), it pulls up this error:

> A Java Runtime Enviroment (JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK) must be
>   available in order to run Eclipse. No Java virtual machine was found
>   after searching the following locations: C:\Users\Eric\Desktop\Eclipse
>   Indigo SR1\eclipse\jre\bin\java.exe java.exe in your current PATH

I installed both a JRE and a JDK, but it still won't run. I'm trying to make sure i'm not making a mistake. When I installed the JRE and JDK, I let them install normally, without changing the install location. After that failed, I installed the JRE to my eclipse folder (C:\Users\Eric\Desktop\Eclipse Indigo SR1\eclipse). All that did was add the files to the folder along with this application file: jdk-7u1-windows-i586. I've pretty much given up on this. Anyone know what i'm doing wrong? I'm running 64-bit Windows 7 Pro.

EDIT: Forgot to add that my eclipse folder is lacking \jre, but has a \bin.

Comment: `C:\Users\Eric\Desktop\Eclipse Indigo SR1\eclipse\jre\bin\java.exe java.exe in your current PATH`. It seems like you have given `java.exe` in your path. Remove that, PATH should be only to bin folder.

Comment: See my [answer on an eclipse question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8223489/move-default-config-folder-of-eclipse/8223728#8223728) on how to define a shortcut (on Windows) to start eclipse. I would recommend that in every situation to control which JDK is used for Eclipse.

Comment: Java command should execute successfully for Eclipse to run without -vm option.

Answer (score 0):

Try this article [FAQ: How do I run Eclipse](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_run_Eclipse?). Pay attention on the paragraph "Find the JVM" - it describes -vm option, which you can use to explicitly define JVM location.