# Change secure storage directory in Eclipse - user.home path issue on Windows

Tags: java, eclipse

I have an issue with saving passwords in Eclipse. None of my passwords are "remembered" and I've found Eclipse tries to save them in a folder my Windows account doesn't have access to.

It tries to save to

```
D:\Users\Administrator\.eclipse\org.eclipse.equinox.security\secure_storage
```

a directory that does not exist and to which my Win account couldn't write anyway.

What I found is that my user.home variable is set to D:\Users\Administrator. My wild guess is that's because it's the Administrator account that installed Java.

So my question is - can I change the user.home path, or at least change some other properties to force Eclipse Secure Storage to work elsewhere?

**edit**: so I found a solution here [What are the best JVM settings for Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse)

I added this to my eclipse.ini:

-eclipse.keyring
C:\some\path\file.txt

Which changed my target password storage file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
-Duser.home=C:\your\path
```

Tested on eclipse luna.

Comment: Great! It's been the only option that made it possible to store all configuration, and eclipse files under the desired location. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The secure storage location is set by the "eclipse.keyring" setting.

To change the storage location to a configuration folder under the eclipse folder with a relative path, add the following before the "-vmargs" line in the eclipse.ini file:

```
-eclipse.keyring
configuration\.eclipse\org.eclipse.equinox.security\secure_storage
```

Otherwise, an absolute path can be used like:

```
-eclipse.keyring
C:\eclipse\configuration\.eclipse\org.eclipse.equinox.security\secure_storage
```

To keep the "secure_storage" file in your user directory, copy it to the location you choose.

Tested with Eclipse Mars.

Answer (score 1):

Im not 100% sure but if you add this line

```
-user c:\some\path
```

to your eclipse.ini or use it as cmd parameter it should work.

Comment: I found my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse

To change where passwords are stored, I needed to add this to my eclipse.ini

-eclipse.keyring
c:\some\path

However, your answer did help my search :)

Answer (score 1):

try to add new arg to eclipse.ini to point to your folder

http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/reference/ref-securestorage-options.htm

it is the only solution i found