# Storing credentials failed in fetch using EGIT

Tags: egit

Initially I had the same problem as described in 
[egit - not authorized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14259265/egit-not-authorized).

First, I successfully cloned the repository from Bitbucket.

Then, I tried to fetch and got the error “not authorized”

However, when I used the advice and clicked “Change Credentials” I received the following error:

"Storing credentials failed

No password provided"

Answer (score 114, accepted):

I had this same problem after updating egit. This advice from another forum worked:

Open up Preferences > General > Security > Secure Storage. Select "OSX Keystore Integration", then click "Change Password..."

If you see a dialog saying "An error occurred while decrypting stored values... Do you want to cancel password change?" Click "No."

This will reset the secure storage master password in the OSX Keystore. You will be asked if you want to provide additional information for password recovery, which is optional.

Comment: I +1'd this brilliant answer! I've had the same problem, here on a Windows (yuck) machine. In my case, it's not "OSX Keystore" but "Windows Integration (64 bit).  I found your answer after trying several other solutions, such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10017395/change-secure-storage-directory-in-eclipse-user-home-path-issue-on-windows but they didn't work. Yours did. Hurray!

Comment: i had to completely remove the git password under content, then it worked-

Comment: This process works on Windows as well (the same 'Change Password' but for 'Windows Integration 64-bit' provider)

Answer (score 27):

The accepted answer didn't work for me. There is another solution - in Eclipse simply navigate to:

```
Preferences > General > Security > Secure Storage > Contents
```

and delete everything.

Comment: Works fine for master password provider "Linux Integration (64 bit)" in Eclipse 2021-09 (4.21.0). Before I tried buttons "Change Password..." and "Clear Passwords" but both resulted in an Eclipse freeze.

Answer (score 10):

If you are running Eclipse on OS X, the other answers may not work. If you change the contents of the Eclipse bundle (either manually or by updating some core features or plugins), the application signature will no longer match and the OSX Keystore Integration will no longer be usable. See [Bug 391455](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=391455) for more information.

Downloading a fresh copy of Eclipse will solve this problem, but as a workaround you can also disable OS X Keystore Integration and use Eclipse's built-in one instead:
[image: Disable OS X Keystore Integration]

Comment: Best way out for Mac :-)

Answer (score 4):

I was having this problem with STS 4.0 where even after saving credential in secure storage, any git pull or PUSH activity was asking for credentials every time.

I followed below steps to resolve the issue

1.Navigate to Preferences > General > Security > Secure Storage 
2. click on content tab and expand which has git credentials.
3. Now delete the selected git credential and close the screen. 
4. When next prompt of credentials pops up, provide your credentials and check the box
store to secure storage. It will not ask for password again.
5. I have also made a video to proof it. refer the [video link here](https://youtu.be/GvaGNADTr04)

Answer (score 1):

I am using **STS** ( *Spring Tool Suite ,Version: 3.9.1.RELEASE,Build Id: 201710111105
Platform: Eclipse Oxygen.1a (4.7.1a)*)

and I resolved it by going to

```
windows->Preferences->General->Security-Secure Storage
```

you can see password tab there might be 2 options under master password providers:

- windows Integration(64bit) with priority as 5
- and another one UI Prompt,

So just uncheck Windows Integration (64bit) checkbox

and click Apply and Close button try to access your git or tool, it will ask you for master password for storage there on it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I am using STS ( Spring Tool Suite ,Version: 3.9.1.RELEASE,Build Id: 201710111105
Platform: Eclipse Oxygen.1a (4.7.1a))
and I resolved it by going to windows->Preferences->General->Security-Secure Storage you can see password tab there might be 2 options under master password providers:-
windows Integration(64bit) with priority as 5
and another one UI Prompt, just uncheck Windows Integration (64bit) checkbox and click Apply and Close button try to access your git or tool , it will ask you for maser password for storage there on it will work.