# How is the location of the .eclipse folder determined?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-indigo

I have two drives, `C:\` and `D:\`. For a while I had Eclipse installed on `D:\`, and assumed that it placed my `.eclipse` folder in `D:\Users\NobleUplift\` because of that. However, a new installation later on `C:\` and Eclipse is still saving `.eclipse` to `D:\Users\NobleUplift\`. Why is Eclipse saving to a drive it should no longer know anything about and how do I change it to save `.eclipse` to `C:\Users\NobleUplift\`?

Comment: Registry setting, probably.

Comment: If that's true it would be very easy to fix. I just don't understand why Eclipse is saving files to a drive without the Eclipse installation on it, without the Java installation on it, and to a directory that is **not** my home directory.

Comment: I don't have a Windows machine handy, but used to develop Java on Windows using Eclipse. You can open up `regedit` and search for the parent folder of the `.eclipse` folder and eventually, if this setting is in the registry, it should turn up on the search. Most likely you can just modify it to start with `%USERPROFILE%` so that it will stay in your profile folder between installations.

Comment: If you find such a setting and successfully modify it, then you'll want to (1) close Eclipse, (2) copy your current `.eclipse` folder to the new location, and (3) start eclipse again. If everything went well your settings will be picked up in the new folder. If the settings change didn't work then you'll still have your original folder as a backup and you can change the setting back to what it was before...hopefully leaving your installation intact until you can figure out what went wrong.

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8223489/move-default-config-folder-of-eclipse